# Ubuntu 14.04 client ldap authentication to 389DS

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-14.04

Im already stuck into the configuration of ldap client in ubuntu 14.04 to authenticate on my Ubuntu 14.04 389DS. Does anyone here can give the procedure for ubuntu 14.04 in setting up ldap client?

Thanks,